# Is it good solution? Hide/views on tabs

Tags: android, tabs, view

I'm programming Android 3.2 application with tabs.
I created tabs on ApplicationBar and few views that are classes extends LinearLayout each with they own layout.
In TabListener the view corresponding to the selected tab is shows and other views are hide.
Is it good solution or it is bad?

P.S. Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that would work. Keep in mind though that your Views stay in memory, so any memory intensive work that a view might be doing will continue, even though it's hidden. Android actually has a widget that simplifies the Tab-pattern:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html

Comment: Thank you for response. Yes it is work but I want to make sure it is correct soltion. TabHost is deprecated in API Android 3.0 and above.

Comment: You could use Fragments instead, if your views represent some sort of functionality then they should be split up into fragments for modularity. Then you can use a FragmentTransaction to dynamically add/remove fragments.